# Weibo error 20112 when attempting to access a user's post

Tags: api, permissions, weibo

I'm attempting to get a user's Weibo post with [2/statuses/show](http://open.weibo.com/wiki/2/statuses/show). I'm able to get posts made by my own account fine, but when I try to get another user's post I get the error:

```
{"error":"Permission Denied!","error_code":20112,"request":"/2/statuses/show.json"}
```

The [Weibo docs](http://open.weibo.com/wiki/Help/error) say (via google translate):

```
20112: As the author privacy settings, you do not have permission to view this microblogging
```

Does this mean the author of the post needs to update their permissions to allow the developer account access?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also encounter this issue. However, you can still access the post using its user_id and mid (in base62). For instance, you cannot get [this post](http://www.weibo.com/1838774143/ezBvUNbtYO7?type=comment) from the API (its id is 10031139424) but you can still see it from your webbrowser.

An alternative is to get the post from its mobile [url](http://m.weibo.cn/status/10031139424). Then, you can get its json which is contained in the variable `render_data` from the body of the html.

Answer (score 0):

Any posts can be setted to be unvisible but for microblogger himself or trusted groups.

So privacy settings lead to your problem.

Comment: Thanks. The microbloggers claimed that they hadn't set any privacy settings, but they must be set by default? Any idea how they could give us permission?